# How to override content of Oozie workflow.xml in Cloudera 5.5.1

Tags: oozie, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to send an attachment with oozie email action.  The attachment is not working because the email action
Here

```
<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.1">
```

does not support attachment but

```
<email xmlns="uri:oozie:email-action:0.2">
```

does.

The problem is when we submit the workflow from coordinator it overrides the content to original email-action:0.1 version.  How should I fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Update the `workflow.xml` file with your changes and replace the `workflow.xml` in HDSF. Next time, when your coordinator executes the workflow it will use the update workflow.